# Usage of zur and zum

Tags: translation, german-to-english

> Morgen gehe ich zur Schule.
>
> Morgen gehe ich zum Fußballspiel.

In both cases the relevant questions would begin with "wohin".
So why does the first sentence require `zur` and the second `zum`?

Isn't the dative masculine and neuter forms of the definite article "dem"? And zu + dem = zum. So why is "Schule" preceded by "zur" (`zu+der`)?

I searched Google and I am not so sure if Schule is masculine.. So if that is the case everything is ok, I am just no sure.

Comment: *Fussballspiel* would be one single word.

Comment: @TonyTannous You can use [Duden](www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/). Enter the word in the search field above and check the gender.

Comment: **Die** Schule is feminin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Die Schule" is feminine and that explains why in the Dativ it is "zu der Schule" or contracted "zur Schule". 
If you are not sure about the gender of a noun, maybe it helps more to check in a dictionary than to just google, e.g., use [Duden](http://www.duden.de/woerterbuch).

Answer (score 3):

"Die Schule" is feminine, so it is "zu der Schule" or "zur Schule".